# Performance issues with saving and loading data from RecyclerView using Moshi

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences, moshi

In my `Fragment` for my Android app, I'm using `SharedPreferences` and `Moshi` to save and load the data I get from my `RecyclerView`.

These are the two functions I have for that task:

```
private fun saveData() {
    val sharedPreferences = this@Main.requireContext().getSharedPreferences("recycler_view", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
    val moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(BigDecimalAdapter).add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()
    val listMyData = Types.newParameterizedType(List::class.java, CardItem::class.java)
    val jsonAdapter : JsonAdapter<ArrayList<CardItem>> = moshi.adapter(listMyData)
    val json = jsonAdapter.toJson(dataList)
    editor.putString("data_list", json)
    editor.apply()
}

private fun loadData() {
    val sharedPreferences = this@Main.requireContext().getSharedPreferences("recycler_view", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val json = sharedPreferences.getString("data_list", null)
    val type : Type = object : TypeToken<List<CardItem>>() {}.type
    val moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(BigDecimalAdapter).add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()
    val jsonAdapter : JsonAdapter<ArrayList<CardItem>> = moshi.adapter(type)
    dataList = jsonAdapter.fromJson(json!!)!!
    if (dataList == null) {
        dataList = arrayListOf<CardItem>()
    }
}
```

In my `onViewCreated` I have this for calling the `loadData()` function and building the `RecyclerView`:

```
loadData()

recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.main_recycler_view)
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
recyclerViewLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@Main.requireContext())
adapter = MainAdapter(dataList, this)
recyclerView.layoutManager = recyclerViewLayoutManager
recyclerView.adapter = adapter
```

Everything works as I want, however, I've noticed a delay/lag when I go to this specific fragment. There are a total of three fragments in my app, the other two work smoothly with no delay/lag, but when I click on the button to go to this fragment or slide the screen to go to this fragment, there's a delay in the switch. What can I do to make the performance with `Moshi` better? Is there anything I can add to my code or modify to make the performance better when saving and loading the `RecyclerView` data?

Comment: Does this happen only on the first app start on the first fragment load, or each time on that fragment?

Comment: @PabloBaxter Only on the third fragment which loads the `RecyclerView` data and every time that fragment is loaded.

Comment: I would add in some logs to do some time tracing around what call is causing the problem. I have a hunch it's your shared prefs, especially if that can be the first load of it. Typically you want to get the shared prefs object on class initialization.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be **The application may be doing too much work on its main thread** issue. Json parsing is CPU intensive task and given that you are parsing a list of objects, this can take some time to execute which causes the observed delay, because you are doing heavy processing on UI thread hence keeping it from drawing the UI. you can verify this using logcat, there must be an entry saying something like `I/Choreographer: Skipped n frames : The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`

So how to fix this?

### Don't do too much work on UI thread, use [Coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines) instead

UI thread should only be used to update UI, such as `textView.text = "someText"` etc. when you need to perform long running tasks, you need to use some background thread, this is very simple in kotlin, you can make your functions use coroutines.

```
private fun loadData() = lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default){
val sharedPreferences = this@Main.requireContext().getSharedPreferences("recycler_view", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
   ...    
}
```

`lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default)` this creates a new coroutine which executes your code on a background thread, rather than the UI. you can also update you `saveData` function in similar way.

Except from the UI thread issue, there is also a design issue in your code. you are doing the JSON parsing everytime the fragment is loaded, which is not very optimal. Instead you should perform the parsing only once and store the result in a [database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room), and then you can simply load the data from database, without needing to perform parsing everytime.

Comment: Since my code is in a fragment, where would I do the parsing from the result I get from my database? For example, `onResume`, `onViewCreated`, etc. I'm using Firebase Realtime Database for storing the JSON string.